# A different form of $GL(V,B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $B:V\times V \to F$ be a bi-linear form.
Suppose that $B$ is given by the matrix $\underline{B}=(B_{ij})$.

How would I show that:
$$GL(V,B):=\{ g \in GL_n(F): B(gu,gv)=B(u,v) \ \ \forall u,v \in V\}$$
satisfies the following:
$$GL(V,B)=\{ g\in GL_n(F): g^t\underline{B}g=\underline{B}\}$$
?

Clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

We have If the coordinate representations of $u,v$ and $B$ are $\underline{u},\underline{v},\underline{B}$ respectively, $B(u,v)=\underline{u}^T\underline{B}\,\underline{v}$. This means that $B(gu,gv)=(g\underline{u})^T\underline{B} g\underline{v}=\underline{u}^Tg^T\underline{B}\, g\underline{v}$. What does this tell us about matrices that preserve $B$?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the coordinate representation you wrote in your first line. After that it's a breeze... i.e trivial.